# d3 scaleBy from the left instead of the center

Tags: javascript, d3.js

We're using d3 to build a graph and it has two custom buttons to handle the zooming as well as the standard zooming via the mousewheel/trackpad.

```
let local = this;

let zoomIn = d3.select("#zoom_in");
let zoomOut = d3.select("#zoom_out");
let reset = d3.select("#reset");

zoomIn.on("click", function() {
  zoom.scaleBy(local.chart.transition().duration(500), 1.2);
});

zoomOut.on("click", function() {
  zoom.scaleBy(local.chart.transition().duration(500), 0.8)
});
```

This zooms the graph fine (including the brush). However it zooms from the centre.

According to the documentation: https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom#zoom_scaleBy scaling from the centre is the default behaviour unless a position is provided... but we haven't been able to figure out what this parameter should actually be...

We have tried:

```
zoom.scaleBy(local.chart.transition().duration(500), 0.8, 0);
```

and also tried to use translateBy: https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom#zoom_translateBy to move it back to the left AFTER the scale:

```
zoom.scaleBy(local.chart.transition().duration(500), 0.8, 0);
zoom.translateBy(local.chart.transition().duration(500), 0, 0);
```

But this cancels out the zoom...

Is there any examples of using `scaleBy` to zoom from a position?

Answer (score 2):

The API docs on [`zoom.scaleBy()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom#zoom_scaleBy) have you covered (emphasis mine):

> *[#](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom#zoom_scaleBy)* *zoom*.scaleBy(*selection*, *k*[, *p*])
>   *[…]*
>   the *p* point may be specified either as **a two-element array [*p<sub>x</sub>*,*p<sub>y</sub>*]** or a function.

By providing a two-element array as the third argument to the call you can specify the center for the zooming. For your code this could be specified as follows:

```
zoom.scaleBy(local.chart.transition().duration(500), 1.2, [0, height / 2]);
                                                       //  ↑  ↑
                                                       // [px,py        ]
```

Similarly, this holds true for `zoom.scaleTo()`, `zoom.translateBy()` and `zoom.translateTo()`.